# Amazon SNS service SMS only with requests package

Tags: python, amazon-sns

I need to send SMS with Amazon SNS service but I can only use the requests package not boto3.

Here is as far as I came.

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"

params = {
    "Action": "Publish",
    "Version": "2010-03-31",
    "PhoneNumber": "+49123456789",
    "Message": "Hello World!",
}

aws_access_key_id = "KEY"
aws_secret_access_key = "SECRET"


response = requests.post(url, data=params, auth=(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key), headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

but I get:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MissingAuthenticationToken</Code>
    <Message>Request is missing Authentication Token</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>xxxxx</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

How do I get the token?

Answer (score 0):

Requests to AWS have to be signed using [sigv4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing-aws-api-requests.html). To use this together with requests in Python, you could leverage [requests-auth-aws-sigv4](https://pypi.org/project/requests-auth-aws-sigv4/)